# Create Notes view for duplicate parent documents

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, lotus-formula

We have an Xpages application and recently discovered an issue where there are several Notes documents that have duplicates but the duplicates are PARENT documents too and NOT response documents.  Is it possible to create a Notes view that will show duplicates where all the duplicates are parents?  I know the formula for showing conflicts is the following but what about where they are all parents?

```
SELECT @IsAvailable($Conflict)
```

Comment: Maybe make a categorized view and if there is more than one category then that would identify your duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

*Expounding on my comment:*

1. Create a view which is categorized on the first column
2. In the first column formula, put in criteria that you would use to determine a duplicate. This may be the Document Unique ID, or maybe another field or combination of fields.
3. Add a second column that contains the number 1. Then enable column totals on this column.

Now look at this view you created. With the view categories collapsed, look for any number greater that 1 to determine which documents are duplicates.

Comment: Replace point 3 with an agent which does the reporting for you, so you don't have to scroll through the view.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is not how to identify the duplicates - but how to find out which of them are parent documents. So basically you would create a view as Steve suggests - but instead of putting a constant of 1 into the second column I would suggest putting either @DocChildren (for immediate responses) or @DocDescendants (for all responses and responses to responses).

If I understand your logic then all the ones returning 0 (zero) are child documents and those returning 1 or higher would be parent documents. Of course you could also use an item on the document in your view formula - if it only exists on the parent doc (or its value can tell that it is a parent doc)

Comment: Not sure if you understand my issue - I am not finding this easy either though as my experience of Notes and XPages is very little so far.  What we have is duplicate Notes documents but instead of one being a Parent and the other(s) a response they are ALL parents even though they have the same Notes application ID.  I have no idea how this has happened.  I will investigate the Categorized view possibility

Comment: Explain what you mean by "Notes application ID". That's not a standard term.

Comment: @JohnDalsgaard By Notes application ID I mean when a new document is created through the XPages front end (A contract) a contract ID is generated, i.e. 9NSJMR and we can have two contracts with the Contract ID 9NSJMR that are both parents for some reason

Answer (score 0):

View selection formulas act on only one document at a time. They cannot perform lookups. They have no way to compare two documents. There is therefore no possible way for a view to identify duplicates.

A view can, as per the other answers, categorize documents based on common values. If there is a single field that is supposed to be unique across all documents, you can categorize on that field. That will give you a visualization of the duplicates, but it won't filter them in or out.

The only way for a view to filter duplicates - either to show only duplicates, or to exlude duplicates - would be if you run an agent that reads all documents, looks for those that are duplicates, and marks them with a special field value - e.g., IsDuplicate = 1. Once you do that, you can create a view that selects all documents with IsDuplicated = 1, or a view that excludes IsDuplicated = 1.